# How to pass the custom SNI with haproxy in TCP mode

Tags: ssl, haproxy, sni

I have a public ssl endpoint something.example.com, which requires SNI extension to be used. I cant access it directly, so I want to pass it through haproxy (which is set up in the server with internet access)

This is not working:
`openssl s_client -connect something.example.com:443`

This is working fine:
`openssl s_client -connect something.example.com:443 -servername something.example.com`

My haproxy config (version 1.8.24):

```
frontend my_frontend
    bind *:443
    mode tcp
    log global
    option tcplog
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
    use_backend my_backend

backend my_backend
    mode         tcp
    server       my-server something.example.com:443 sni str(something.example.com)
```

When Im logged in the haproxy server, I can do:

`curl -v https://something.example.com/` and can see the SSL connection is established

but when doing `curl -v https://127.0.0.1/` Im facing:

curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 127.0.0.1:443

What is wrong? I already tried to terminate ssl, replace the host header but with no luck. My understanding is that SNI itself is separated from ciphered request and with above configuration I should be able to connect to backend.

PS. Backend server is not managed by me.

---

EDIT: as stated in the comments, it is impossible to pass custom SNI in TCP mode configuration. Following can be done for http mode, with TLS termination, below is working fine:

```
frontend log_frontend
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/pki/tls/private/mycert.pem
    mode http
    log global
    option httplog
    option forwardfor
    use_backend log_backend

backend log_backend
    mode         http
    server       my-server something.example.com:443 ssl verify none sni str(something.example.com)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that SNI itself is separated from ciphered request ...

SNI is part of the SSL/TLS handshake, specifically the ClientHello sent at the beginning of the handshake by the client. **It is impossible to replace any part of the TLS handshake, including SNI**. Instead TLS need to be terminated (which means proper certificates etc are needed) and then a new TLS session has to be created with the expected SNI set.

Comment: Hey Steffen, you might be right, however I understood that haproxy in TCP mode still can decipher SNI itself and for example route based on this. Since its TCP mode, it cant handle any headers etc. Are you sure SNI is intouchable then? Looking at official docs: "The 'sni' parameter evaluates the sample fetch expression, converts it to a string and uses the result as the host name sent in the SNI TLS extension to the server". --> IMO "sni str()" should then do exactly what I need.

Comment: Can you please help me with configuration for TLS termination and puting proper SNI? This is what I have for now, can't find out how to enable SNI here. Tried replacing header or seting it in backend section, no luck. I have requested certificate for haproxy server and can see TLS connection is being established, but its not going to backend.

Comment: I have added configuration in the main post. Since I do not manage backend, should I leave here `ssl verify none`?

Comment: @borubar: Like I said, SNI can not be changed in TCP mode. It can be read so decisions based on it can be made. But changing SNI would break the integrity of the TLS handshake and the handshake would fail.

Comment: Got it, let it be. Can you comment configuration for http mode? Its not working, I can only connect to haproxy frontend, but getting 503 from the backend.

```* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, close notify (256):
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)```

Comment: @borubar: *"Can you comment configuration for http mode?"* - this is a different question. Your original one was answered. Please ask a new question for new problems and include all details there. Don't make your question a moving target.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. I confirm what I have been trying to do is impossible in TCP mode, as you said. In the main post I have left working solution with HTTP mode. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Well I assume you will also get something like "Certificate does not match hostname" in the call `curl -v https://127.0.0.1/`.

I strongly suggest to tell curl how to resolve the something.example.com

```
curl -v --resolve something.example.com:443:127.0.0.1 https://something.example.com/
```

A more detailed explanation is in this blog post
https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2018/04/05/curl-another-host/

BTW: I strongly recommend to updat to the latest LTS version of haproxy 2.4

Comment: Thanks Aleksandar for you input. You are right, however I already ensured that my configuration works fine when I do specify server name. What I need to do is to make it working without this, so that haproxy will take care on what is being send to backend server. About haproxy version - fully agree, however I work in extremely secure environment, based on RHEL, so usually there is only 1.5.18 available - its still a surpsise that I was allowed to use 1.8.24 from software collections.